# Implementing OAuth 2 protocol in existing asp.net project, for third party integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

I work with an existing asp.net website with forms authentication. We are interested in integrating a third party service with single sign on, we do not want our users to login to their site when accessing the link.

We are trying to use OAuth 2 standard for this, but as we do not have any experience with that we can't clearly understand the flow.

We need to make transactions with the external website on behalf of the user, so we should provide them with some way to identify the user and verify that they are authenticated in our website.

So far,I have created a Web Api to be accessible to the third party. I have managed to implement Owin and Identity, i want to use the bearear token that is generated to keep the user id ( with ClaimsIdentity) and send it to the third party when the user is logged in to my site and wants to access the other application, so they will know who the user is and if he is authenticated . I don't know if this is a good approach. Any help would be apprecciated

Answer (score 0):

That's very broad topic and broad question.

I would recommend starting with [DotNetOpenAuth library](http://dotnetopenauth.net). Authorization flows are covered in [Oauth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4) as well as best practices recommendations etc. If you want users to use external website to sign in and then log in to your website with those credentials, "4.1. Authorization Code Grant" is workflow you are looking for.

Comment: No, i do not want users to use external website to sign in, i want them to sign in into my website and then access the other website without the need to sign in there(we should provide for the third party a way to authenticate the user that is accessing it). We should also give them information about the user to identify. Does it mean i should build an authorization server?

Comment: Got it. Yes, you need to build authorization server. You can certainly do this with DotNetOpenAuth. I've done this for company I'm working on

Comment: Can you please recommend me a good tutorial to start with? Should i build the DotNetOpenAuth on top of my existing website or create a web Api as the authorization server? Thank you for your replies

Comment: I used samples from DotNetOpenAuth source code. https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/tree/develop/samples Also this can be helpful https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Security-scenarios

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting by having a look at Taiseer Joudeh's Tutorials on OAuth, they are excellent and well supported by the community.

http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

This will give you a clearer vision about how oAuth is handled with Web Api 2 and Owin middleware.

If you are working on a Asp.Net Core project, I have a github project which you can use as a starter kit using oAuth + Aurelia + signalR.

https://github.com/alexandre-spieser/AureliaAspNetCoreAuth

How this helps.